# Lumia 630 dual sim Windows Phone showing update demo content instead of phone reset in about

Tags: nokia-lumia-630

I did hard reset on my phone which is Nokia Lumia 630 Dual Sim, after resetting, I got what I think may be bugs. I am mentioning them one by one as follows:

1. I am unable to hard reset my phone when I go to settings > about and there is not Reset button is appearing and it is replace by the button "Update Demo Content". I don't know why it is appearing instead of the Reset option. It gave me lots of frustration.
2. There is an anonymous outlook id account appearing in email+account section something like "RDM014885537106@outlook.com" and the same I am unable to delete it and unable to add more account since I am tapping to add more account but it is redirecting me to add new account section.
3. Some text message threads and miss call notifications still appearing in action centre. I tried to remove them but they are not removing from there, every time I swipe down I see them still appearing.
4. Some options / features became disabled

I don't know what just happened to my phone. I bought it two weeks ago.

Please help me.

Comment: Where did you buy your phone, was it a demo unit?

Comment: How did you perform the hard reset?

Comment: @NeilTurner I had bought my phone from an authorized dealer of Nokia and it was not a demo unit

Comment: @RowlandShaw I did hard reset by menu: settings. After discussions some other forums I noticed that we can have two times of this type of reset and if we go for the third time then it will flash the Demo rom and will become a Demo unit. Well I have resolved this and it's working fine as it should be.

Comment: @Lightcoder *How* did you resolve it - you should add your solution as an answer, should this be a problem to someone else...

Comment: Please let me know how you resolved it. My brother is facing the same issue with his Lumia 630!

Comment: Hi @Apoorva I have written an answer and explained step-by-step, enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

## This is how I did it...

We will have to perform the **hardreset** for our Lumia 630, follow the steps at below:

**Note before proceed:**
This will erase all of your personal saved data and your phone will be restored to its factory settings. Make sure your battery level is strong enough more than 50% you can also check your remaining battery level by going to Settings > battery saver. In case if you are not checking it and the battery life is too low, then charge your phone for 20 minutes approx.

1. With the phone powered-off, press and hold the **Power** key until the vibration and then release.
2. Press and hold the **Volume Down** key until the appearance of the exclamation mark on the screen, after that you can release the volume down key.
3. Then press the volume and power keys with the pattern as below:
4. **Volume Up** key
5. **Volume Down** key
6. **Power** key
7. **Volume Down** key
8. You will see the animated cog icons of the setting will be appeared in the screen to show that the restoring is on progress and will take few minutes.
9. Then finally your phone will be reset to its factory settings.