# How to put my phone in demo mode?

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-930

I have a Nokia Lumia 930 and I'd like to put it in demo mode like in the stores. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Soletiles I'd like to put phones in stores in demo mode.

Comment: @Shawn maybe jst out of curiosity. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to wipe it. Go to Settings > About and tap on "Device Information" five times. Then scroll down and you'll see a button that says "Enable demo mode".

Comment: Finally! And how to deactivate it again?

Comment: As far as I know that does require a reset. I don't have a phone in demo mode right now, but I think you do it by tapping Device Info 5 times again, then scrolling down. It should give you a reset button.

Answer (score 3):

You need a special phone /  rom for that, a normal phone can't be set up that way. 
You could perhaps make use of the apps corner or kids corner for demo purposes.

Comment: [this](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/lumia-630-dual-sim-windows-phone-showing-update-demo-content-instead-of-phone-re) post says something else since the person accidentally put his device in demo mode.

Comment: Well I can't find anything on the web that would back up his claims. I am a 100% sure what I said is true for Windows Phone 7 devices (I worked for a carrier back then), and I can't imagine this has changed with WP8.

Comment: I was given a demo phone from Nokia and can confirm that it runs a completely different ROM and I was unable to demo mode on/off.